# Django many to many admin with custom through object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

lets assume that I have such a model:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        db_table = mysql_membership
```

So my in-the-middle table is chosen (and manually created) by me. And now I would like to create the admin with inline formset in for Group objects. Just like this:

```
class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Membership
    extra = 1

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)

admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

The problem is, that when I try to get edit form for a given Group, I get this error:

```
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

(1054, "Unknown column 'mysql_membership.id' in 'field list'")
```

This is understandable to me because the primary key in this mysql_membership table is a set of columns (instead of one simple primary_key column):

```
PRIMARY KEY (person, group, invite_reason)
```

I want you to know, that I CAN'T edit the database schema. How can I enable formset for many-to-many field based on custom "through" table/model? Please help.

btw. I was using example from:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models